# Not getting the same result from running a python script to generate a certain input string as i get when typing it myself

Tags: c, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow, machine-code

I have the following code and I'm trying to buffer overflow it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run `run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` on `gdb` I get the following output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
```

When I try to give my string of As through a file or a python script I get the following

```
(gdb) run < attack.txt 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08055718 in __strcpy_sse2 ()
```

I get the same output with the following command

```
(gdb) run <<< $(python -c 'print("\x41"*20)')
```

So what exactly is happening here?

Comment: I don't think gdb supports `<<<` here-strings or command substitution

Comment: You're trying to use bash syntax inside gdb. It's not a full shell like that.

Comment: The "<<<" makes the string the stdin of your program, but you want it as your argument, so remove it.

Comment: thanks, it works when i just give ```run $(python -c 'print("\x41"*20)')```, but i still have the same problem, when i try to give the input from a file. when i just type in ```run attack.txt```, my program exits normally, no matter how large my input in the file is, and and i give ```run < attack.txt``` i get the error posted in the question @ssbssa

Comment: Of course you get that error, `run < attack.txt` also puts the contents of the file as stdin, and not as argument. I don't understand why you expect a different result.